# TSQL output the row count

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that is outputting my results in XML format; all is good with the output.

I need to however include the row count it is outputting if possible along with it.

```
 SELECT A.[id],
             A.[petName],
             A.[petCaption],
             B.[petType],
             C.[FirstName] as ownerFirstName,
             C.[LastName] as ownerLastName,
             A.[imageName],

             (
                SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),sum(transactionAmount), 1) as totalRaised
                FROM petContestTransactionsDonations
                WHERE submissionID = A.[id]
                FOR    XML PATH ('transactionDetails'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
             )
      FROM petContestSubmissions as A
      LEFT OUTER JOIN petContestTypes as B
      ON A.[petType] = B.[id]
      LEFT OUTER JOIN EmpTable as C
      ON A.[empID] = C.EmpID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN petContestTransactionsEntries as E
      ON E.[submissionID] = A.[id]
      WHERE E.[transactionStatus] = 'completed'
     ORDER BY A.[id] 
        OFFSET  @offset ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT @rows ROWS ONLY 
      FOR    XML PATH ('submission'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

I am passing `offset` and `rows` to the stored procedure as I am using it with pagination. It is getting records for that page limiting to X rows.

Even though I say get me the next 10 records, it may only have 8 left. That's what I need to return; the total records it found in the select statement.

Is it best to do that in the stored procedure or in my php that is looping over the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the row count on each row, then include:

```
count(*) over () as RowCount
```

in the outermost `select` clause.

If you want to read all the data into the application first, then do it in the application layer.

EDIT:

If you want the number of rows returned by the query, then you might as well do it in the application layer.  You can also do:

```
select t.*, count(*) over () as RowCOunt
from (<your query here>) t;
```

Comment: Hm, well this ignores the offset and rows and gets my the count of all the records in that table. I need to find out how many records are returned in just the select. The plugin I am using says "Get me 10 rows starting from row 5. It will only return 10 rows max but if there is less, I need to know the count so the script knows that there is no more data.

Comment: @SBB . . . I thought your question was *about* the number of records in the table as opposed to the offset.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will meet your needs.  Not in the same query, but you can try

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS RowsAffected
```

immediately after your query, you should get what you are looking for.  @@ROWCOUNT is per session, so as long as you don't end your connection, should be ok.